# xcode Unzip Downloaded issue

Tags: xcode, unzip, newsstand-kit, ssziparchive

I'm working on typical newsstand app and I have problem with unzipping downloaded file.

> -(void)connectionDidFinishDownloading:(NSURLConnection *)connection destinationURL:(NSURL *)destinationURL {
>
> // copy the file to the destination directory
>
> NSURL *finalURL = [[self contentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"magazine.zip"];
>      ELog(@"Copying item from %@ to %@",destinationURL,finalURL);
>
> [[NSFileManager defaultManager] copyItemAtURL:destinationURL toURL:finalURL error:NULL];
>      [[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:NULL];
>
> // Downloaded file magazine.zip is in finalURL now and in next step I will try to unzip it
>
> [SSZipArchive unzipFileAth:[finalURL path] toDestinan:[[self contentURL]path] overwrite:YES password:nil error:nil];
>
> [self sendEndOfDownloadNotification];
>   }

And nothing happens. I checked if the file is really located at finalURL path and yes it is. The SSZipArchive has problem to open the magazine.zip file. I tried to find some example how to unzip downloaded Newsstand issue but I didn't find anything.

Answer (score 1):

destinationURL is the temporary path of zip file you downloaded. You should directly unzip the file from here to destination

```
    [SSZipArchive unzipFileAth:[destinationURL path] toDestination:[[self contentURL] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"magazine.zip"] overwrite:YES password:nil error:nil]; 
//Remove temp file
[[NSFileManager defaultManager] removeItemAtURL:destinationURL error:NULL];
```